# using strace with mpiexec

Tags: mpi, strace, mpich, mpiexec

How do I strace all processes of MPI parallel job, started with mpiexec (MPICH2, linux)?

`-o` will mess outputs from different processes

PS To some editors: who may think that `MPICH is the name of the library. MPICH2 is a particular version.`. MPICH2 is actually `MPICH2 is an all-new implementation of MPI` and I sometimes had to used both mpich and mpich2. So, we can't replace mpich2 with mpich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper around your program, which will be launched by `mpiexec`. Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGFILE="strace-$(hostname).$$"
exec strace -o"$LOGFILE" my_mpi_program
```

Comment: It's ok, file names still will be different due to $$ part -- it is the PID of the current process.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try STAT (Stack Trace Analysis Tool).
Check out the [STAT Homepage](http://www.paradyn.org/STAT/STAT.html).
It will give you a high level overview of your process behavior, and works
especially well in the case of a hung process.

Comment: sorry. this project is interesting, but i can't run it on target platform (StackWalker API  is not ported, but strace is).

Comment: What platform is it?  Try using gcc 4.1.2, we've had problems compiling with newer versions (StackWalker specifically).